# How can we automate built-in apps with espresso?

Tags: android, android-espresso

Is it possible to automate built-in apps like device "Settings" with the help of Espresso?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, no, because Espresso is reliant on activities. However this should be possible with [UI Automator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator)

Answer (score 0):

yes, We can automate everything using Espresso. Try any available emulator and locator finder to get the proper resource details to automate it.

Use any of the available 22 Resource methods to identify. The 22 methods are as follows

1. R.anim
2. R.animator
3. R.array
4. R.attr
5. R.bool
6. R.color
7. R.dimen
8. R.drawable
9. R.fraction
10. R.id
11. R.integer
12. R.interpolator
13. R.layout
14. R.menu
15. R.mipmap
16. R.plurals
17. R.raw
18. R.string
19. R.style
20. R.styleable
21. R.transition
22. R.xml